# How to convert string to class constructor

Tags: python, string, class

How do I convert a class name to a class constructor ?

### Example

Let say we have a method that takes two strings as input, first the output type, and then the value to convert. Here are some example of outputs:

- foo("int", "12") would return 12
- foo("str", "12") would return "12"
- foo("float", "12") would return 12.0

What is the content of foo(), without using pydoc.locate() ?

*edit: getattr(sys.modules[**name**], str) works with new classes, but not with systems classes. Then it's not a valid solution for my problem*

Comment: `eval(...)` or `ast.literal_eval(...)` with security measures. Or rethink your approach without strings.

Comment: Have you consider passing int/str/float argument as a class instead of a string?

Comment: `import builtins; getattr(builtins, 'int')('12')`

Comment: Thanks @deceze ! That is working perfectly !

Comment: Sanely you should have a dict `{'int': int, ...}` from which you can easily convert string values to classes and prevent arbitrary classes from being used. If you're just after builtins, you can use the `builtins` module as shown above, but that includes access to `eval`, and at that point, you may indeed just use `eval` directly…